# Identify methodinfo that has HTTPPost() attribute

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently reading the controllers from the assembly with the below

```
Public Shared Function GetControllers() As List(Of Type)
    ' Go through all assemblies referenced by the application and search for
    ' controllers and controller factories.

    Dim controllerTypes As New List(Of Type)()
    Dim Assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies
    For Each assembly As Reflection.Assembly In Assemblies
        Dim typesInAsm As Type()
        Try
            typesInAsm = assembly.GetTypes()
        Catch ex As Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException
            typesInAsm = ex.Types
        End Try
        controllerTypes.AddRange(typesInAsm.Where(AddressOf IsControllerType))
    Next
    Return controllerTypes
End Function
```

Then the list which I have just populated is used to read all the actions now I am trying to filter out the ones that have HTTPPost.

```
Public Shared Sub GetActionMethods(Controllers As List(Of Type))
    For Each y In Controllers
        Dim selector = New ActionMethodSelector(y)

        Dim allValidMethods As New List(Of Reflection.MethodInfo)()
        allValidMethods.AddRange(selector.AliasedMethods)
        allValidMethods.AddRange(selector.NonAliasedMethods.SelectMany(Function(g) g))

        Dim z = allValidMethods.ToArray()
    Next
End Sub
```

The thing is I don't know how to set up the where to do it through linq. I tried various methods but I always end up with an empty list.

```
Dim k = (From o As Reflection.MethodInfo In allValidMethods
         Select o).ToArray
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find my solution on another website and to give credit I will be posting the link.

[Using LINQ with System.Reflection Classes](http://weblogs.asp.net/ysolodkyy/using-linq-with-system-reflection-classes)

My code is here under

```
Dim k = (From o As Reflection.MethodInfo In allValidMethods
         Where o.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(HttpPostAttribute), True).Length > 0
         Select o).ToArray
```